# How to clone from a previous deploy on Heroku

Tags: heroku, rollback, git-clone

So, I have seen previous posts like this on this site, specifically on the post here [Cloning a previous version on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903629/cloning-a-previous-version-on-heroku), but the last step never works. I am not sure if this is just because the CUI has updated a lot or if I am just doing it wrong, but whenever I do `git checkout 242425` it never works (I just made up the deploy id)

If someone could help me out that would be amazing, but keep it simple and just do it step-by-step as I am still quite new to Heroku and co. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does "never works" mean? Does it fail silently? Do yo get an error message? If so, what does it say? Please read [ask].

Comment: Also, please note that [cloning from Heroku is an antipattern](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app): "Heroku provides the git service primarily for deployment, and the ability to clone from it is offered as a convenience. We strongly recommend you store your code in another git repository such as [GitHub](https://github.com/) and treat that as canonical."